# Joining on table-valued function slows down query

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-execution-plan

`Orders` is 350k rows. `Users` is 20k rows. `Reflinks` is 2k rows. `@p0` is 40k ids. `SplitIds(@p0)` splits `@p0` and returns `TABLE(Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY)`. Looks like it executes immediately.

First `SELECT` executes immediately and returns 7.5k rows. Its execution plan completely based on 'Hash Match' blocks.

Second `SELECT` executes 120s and returns same 7.5k rows. Its execution plane same, but based on `Nested Loop` blocks.

Is it possible somehow to speed up the second query? My task is to explicitly specify the list of input orders, that's why I created `SplitIds`. If you know how to do it without `SplitIds` - your ideas will be appreciated too.

```
DECLARE @p0 varbinary(max);
SET @p0 = 0x.........; // LOT OF BYTES 

SELECT Orders.Id, Reflinks.Rate1
FROM Orders
INNER JOIN Users ON Orders.UserId = Users.Id
INNER JOIN Reflinks ON Users.ReflinkId = Reflinks.Id

SELECT Orders.Id, Reflinks.Rate1
FROM SplitIds(@p0) AS t0
INNER JOIN Orders ON t0.Id = Orders.Id
INNER JOIN Users ON Orders.UserId = Users.Id
INNER JOIN Reflinks ON Users.ReflinkId = Reflinks.Id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are willing to use temporary tables, you could store the result from `SplitIds` in a properly indexed temporary table, and perform the second query using it instead. That will certainly speed up things, because SQL Server will be able to create a better execution plan for the query.

```
CREATE TABLE #temp(Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY)

INSERT INTO #temp(Id) SELECT Id FROM SplitIds(@p0)

SELECT Orders.Id, Reflinks.Rate1
FROM #temp AS t0
INNER JOIN Orders ON t0.Id = Orders.Id
INNER JOIN Users ON Orders.UserId = Users.Id
INNER JOIN Reflinks ON Users.ReflinkId = Reflinks.Id
```

Comment: Agreed with @Guillermo Gutiérrez, and also want to suggest to try with table variable also like '@Table' with Unique constraint which creates non-clustered index. Even, you can try with non-clustered index with above mentioned #table also.

Comment: Sir, I tried your version. It really works. Execution plan became same as in my first version. But most importantly, it gave me to realize that real bottleneck is `SplitIds` itself. http://stackoverflow.com/q/34556299/758815