# INSERT INTO slows down table-valued FUNCTION

Tags: sql-server, performance

On the SQL Server 2008 side I have the table-valued function, that receives 45k of integer ids merged into single `VARBINARY(MAX)`, splits them and returns back as a table. `SplitIds` takes up to 5s. As I see in the **estimated** execution plan - 100% is 'Table Insert'. Is it possible somehow to speed up this function?

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitIds](@data VARBINARY(MAX))
RETURNS @result TABLE(Id INT NOT NULL)
AS
BEGIN
    IF @data IS NULL
        RETURN
    DECLARE @ptr INT = 0, @size INT = 4
    WHILE @ptr * @size < LEN(@data)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @result(Id)
        VALUES(SUBSTRING(@data, @ptr * @size + 1, @size))
        SET @ptr += 1
    END
    RETURN
END
```

Currently on the C# side it is used in Linq-to-SQL query in the next way:

```
XDbOrder[] orders =
    database.SplitIds(ConvertToVarbinary(orderIds))
    Join(
        database.Get<XDbOrder>,
        r = r.Id,
        o => o.Id,
        (r, o) => o).
    ToArray();
```

More general question: is it possible somehow in Linq-to-SQL to implement the next thing without `SplitIds`? `.Contains` does not work - it creates the query with more than 2100 SQL parameters and crashes.

```
int[] orderIds = { ... 45k random entries .....};

XDbOrder[] orders =
    database.Get<XDbOrder>().
    Where(o => orderIds.Contains(o.Id)).
    ToArray();
```

Comment: Of course the table insert is 100%, as that is the only thing the function is doing...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try a more set based approach.

(I've kept the multi statement TVF approach because the inline approach to generating a table of numbers works well in isolation but the execution plans when incorporated into a larger query can be quite catastrophically bad - this ensures that the split happens once and only once)

I've also added a Primary Key to the return table so it contains a useful index.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitIds](@data VARBINARY(MAX))
RETURNS @result TABLE(Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY=ON))
AS
  BEGIN
      IF @data IS NULL
        RETURN

      DECLARE @size INT = 4;

      WITH E1(N)
           AS (SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
               SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
               SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1), -- 1*10^1 or 10 rows
           E2(N)
           AS (SELECT 1 FROM   E1 a, E1 b), -- 1*10^2 or 100 rows
           E4(N)
           AS (SELECT 1 FROM   E2 a, E2 b), -- 1*10^4 or 10,000 rows
           E8(N)
           AS (SELECT 1 FROM   E4 a, E4 b), -- 1*10^8 or 100,000,000 rows
           Nums(N)
           AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1
               FROM   E8)
      INSERT INTO @result
                  (Id)
      SELECT TOP (DATALENGTH(@data)/@size) SUBSTRING(@data, N * @size + 1, @size)
      FROM   Nums

      RETURN
  END
```

The following completes in about 160ms for me

```
DECLARE @data VARBINARY(MAX) = 0x

WHILE DATALENGTH(@data) < 184000
  SET @data = @data + CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(8000)

SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM   [dbo].[SplitIds](@data)
```

Comment: Works like a charm. 0s is required now. Thank you.

Comment: Do not quite undertand why, but it does not work for single id 0x00006120. It works for 0x0000611F or 0x000006121, and works for 0x0000611F0000612000006121. Any ideas?

Comment: @Denis - Replace `LEN` with `DATALENGTH` - `0x20` is treated as a trailing space and not counted.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my version of set based approach

```
create FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitIds1](@data VARBINARY(MAX))
returns table with SCHEMABINDING
as
return
WITH e1(n) AS
(
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
), -- 10
e2(n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM e1 CROSS JOIN e1 AS b), -- 10*10
e3(n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM e1 CROSS JOIN e2), -- 10*100
e4(n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM e3 A CROSS JOIN e3 B), -- 1000*1000
Numbers(ptr,Size) AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY n)-1,4 FROM e4)
SELECT SUBSTRING(@data, ptr * Size + 1, Size) as Id
FROM Numbers
WHERE ptr * Size < LEN(@data)
```

Few notes about my approach

- Adding `SCHEMABINDING` to the function will avoid unnecessary `Table
  spool` operator in `execution plan`
- Also removed `@size` variable since it is hard coded inside function
- Changed `Multi-Statement` Table-Valued Function to `Inline` Table-Valued Function which allows you to see `execution plan` of select statement inside function just like any `view` or `select` query

Comment: This doesn't currently either compile (`'Numbers' has more columns than were specified in the column list.`) or return correct results (only returns 1000 rows instead of 46000 when running the script at the bottom of my answer).

Comment: @MartinSmith - Sorry, now I don't have SSMS to validate the query

Comment: @MartinSmith - updated the tally CTE to increase the row count

Comment: Use SQL fiddle to validate it.

Comment: @MartinSmith - something wrong with Fiddle it is not working here else i will validate for sure